# How to merge two post in one on Laravel5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, postgresql-9.5

I want to post that merged date and timestamp('H:i') like this.

```
private function update($test, $request)
{
    $test -> merge_date = $request -> date . " " . $request -> timestamp_hi;
    $test->save();
}
```

date value comes like '2016-08-30',
timestamp_hi value comes like '12:45'.

I wish to merge there value and set DB record like '2016-08-30 12:45:00'.

But that bring me error.

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
Unexpected data found.
Data missing

at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '12:45:00') in Model.php line 2969
```

If I set timestamp_hi value to '2016-08-30 12:45:00', Carbon create comes like this.

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
The separation symbol could not be found
Unexpected data found.
Trailing data

at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-08-30 2016-08-30 12:45:00') in Model.php line 2969
```

It seems I can merge 2 post but not work on timestamp('H:i'). Why?

P.S.

Model changed this. I don't set protected $dates and Attribute before.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['date', 'timestamp_hi'];
    protected $dates = ['date', 'timestamp_hi'];

    public function getDateAttribute($date)
    {
        return $this->attributes['date'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date) -> toDateString();
    }
    public function getTimestampHiAttribute($timestamp_hi)
    {
        return $this->attributes['timestamp_hi'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp_hi) -> format('H:i');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at your error message.

```
Data missing

at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '12:45:00') in Model.php line 2969
```

The above tells you that you are trying to parse `12:45:00` into format `Y-m-d H:i:s`, you're missing the date for this. It should be `Y-m-d H:i:s, 2016-08-30 12:45:00`, check your `$request->date` by dd() it out. Is there really value being passed in?

```
Trailing data

at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-08-30 2016-08-30 12:45:00') in Model.php line 2969
```

2nd error as above tells you that you've an extra date being passed in, notice the repeats of `2016-08-30`, I believe passing in the right value accordingly to the date format specified wouldn't yield you the error you're facing.

Comment: Thanks to reply. I found incorrect value coming on $request -> date. that value comes like '2016-08-30 00:00:00'. I'm adjust and solve this..

Comment: Welcome to SO @qwe001, glad that it helps, kindly mark it as answered if it solves your problem :)

Comment: Not yet solve this hehe 8< I adjust date value but same problem occured. can't merge date and timestamp to strings?

Comment: I edit my question check that. I change model for delete date 00:00:00 strings. I think date value comes '2016-08-30' and timestamp_hi value comes '12:45'. Front page display so. But I had same .. data missing occured. Should not use date ? use 2 timestamp is make this easy?

Comment: Finally I decide to separate 4 forms. date, hour, minute and second.
Just merge this like $test -> ts = $request -> date . ' ' . $test -> timestamp_h . ':' . $request -> timestamp_i . ':' . $request -> timestamp_s;
I know this is temporary solution. But I don't have enough time to think about it. That's all for now Thank you answer my question twice.